Does this sentence convey my idea? => "This flower holds profound traditional significance for the locals."

This flower holds profound traditional significance for the locals.

I want to say that when it comes to the locals' traditions and cultures, this type of flowers means a lot to them. I've tried looking for the phrase "hold traditional significance" for a while but haven't seen many results.

Your phrase is 100% grammatical but is tending towards formal/academic. If that's your target audience, it's fine as is, though "traditional significance" is a very broad phrase and so it should be backed up with particular examples.  But if you want it to sound more conversational, you could say "has deep traditional meaning for the locals".

I agree with @TimR, except to say that in British English we would see 'the locals' as pretty informal, unlike the preceding part of the sentence. 'Local inhabitants' would be better if you are aiming for a formal or schoolwork level.

It's worth noting that in English traditional can have both positive and negative connotations depending on the context or the audience. I wonder if profound cultural significance is a better option, given that word is already mentioned.

Yes, "the locals" is informal also in AmE. You could eliminate that phrase entirely as the word "traditional" already implies that people and customs are involved. If the flower is meaningful to a tribe, you wouldn't refer to the tribe as "the locals", and if the flower is meaningful to a nation's customs or throughout an entire geographic region you wouldn't  say "the locals" or "local inhabitants" either.

@PeterKirkpatrick  "traditional significance" and "traditional meaning" have a clear positive spin or simple neutrality.  Traditional views, on the other hand, could raise the concern you mention.

The sentence is correct. The flower has profound significance in local culture/ tradition/ custom. Do you mean to say that the flower is worshipped by the locals?

I would add that many Brits would see use of 'the locals' as condescending, sneering, dismissive, etc, or implying hayseed or yokel status.

Based on your explanation, sure, this conveys that meaning. Don't be dismayed by not finding a lot of examples; when I google hold traditional significance—a simple query of three words—I get a lot of results about traditions that don't necessarily use that phrase. But when I google "hold traditional significance", with quote marks, I'm searching for the exact phrase, and I find lots of results. I would also try "holds traditional significance" to match singulars, and I would try all this at Google Books as well as the plain internet.
There are any number of small changes you could make if you want. As many comments have pointed out, "the locals" would probably be replaced by the actual appropriate name of "the locals." And if the flower figures in their "traditions and cultures," and we're differentiating between those concepts, then you could say "... holds profound traditional and cultural significance." And of course it would be good to follow this rather vague sentence with more details about exactly what "profound significance" looks like in this case.
